# WPF height and scroll at listbox - imposible

Tags: wpf, listbox

To keep things simple all i am trying to do is to place a `listbox` and a button below it. Although it seems simple it isn't.  It is not, because it is in a GRID...

The row size is star size and `listbox` having `verticalAlign` top works great all the time. The problem is that I cannot add a button below it. Having a grid with 2 rows one star height and the other auto would place the button at the bottom of the form even if `listbox` contents are little.  Trying to set both rows auto doesn't work when resizing as no scrollbar is visible at the `listbox`....  Any workaround for this??

Update some code

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"  />
           <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
         </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DockPanel >

       <ListBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" Name="lbStaff"  ItemsSource="{Binding}"  
            Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderThickness="0" 
               Background="WhiteSmoke" Margin="15,10,20,30" Style="{DynamicResource 
               ListBoxUsers}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
       <ListBox.Resources>
         <Style  TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource 
            ListBoxTest1}"></Style>
       </ListBox.Resources>
         <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate >
                 <StackPanel Margin="5,4,5,4">
                     <TextBlock   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  FontSize="16"><Run 
                     Text="{Binding Name}"/> - <Run Text="{Binding   Mode=OneWay, 
                     Path=PositionString}"/></TextBlock>
                     <TextBlock >Τηλέφωνο <Run Text="{Binding Phone}"/>
                 </TextBlock>
                 </StackPanel>

             </DataTemplate>
           </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>
     <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" Grid.Row="0"   HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
       VerticalAlignment="Top"  Margin="0,10,7,0" Style="{DynamicResource 
        ButtonStyleNew1}">
       <Button.Content>
           <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
               <Image Source="/WpfApplication1;component/Images/filenew1.png" 
               Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Center"></Image>
               <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" FontSize="16">Προσθήκη Χρήστη</TextBlock>
          </StackPanel>
      </Button.Content>
     </Button>
  </DockPanel>                       

</Grid>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using a dockpanel. I docked buttons at bottom and then i let listbox to fill the remaining area..(lastchildfill=true) ...

It works fine...

Answer (score 1):

What i usually do is not using rows of grid but using DockPanel you can adjust the alignments by nesting each elements. But again it totally depends on the designer how they design that using grid row or any other way.  What i got from the question the following code should help you out.
but if you post some code then we can figure out where the actual problem is.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DockPanel>
        <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <ListBox Height="50"/>
        </DockPanel>
        <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
            <Button Height="20" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
            <Label/>
        </DockPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: i tried that and although it works it has a problem.Button is hidden and then listbox starts to have scrollbars... i am going to update my question with some code.

Answer (score 1):

So your problem here is that you have the  in the `ListBox` you have ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollbars=Visible that  make it collapsed if you dont want scrollbars and i would suggest not to use margins more in the designing. if you still have scroll bars remove the height of the `ListBox` and make the window larger. It all depends upon the size of the window if you don't have the size and proper alignment.  Refining your code

```
<Window xmlns:my="clr-
 namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit" 
    x:Class="MyLightWpfApplication.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyLightWpfApplication.ViewModel"
    DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Skins/MainSkin.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>

</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <DockPanel  >
        <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Width="400" Height="200">
        <ScrollViewer DockPanel.Dock="Top" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ListBox Name="lbStaff"  ItemsSource="{Binding AutoCompleteData}"  
          BorderThickness="0" 
           Background="WhiteSmoke" >

            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <StackPanel >
                        <TextBlock   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  FontSize="16"><Run 
                 Text="{Binding FirstName}"/> - <Run Text="{Binding   Mode=OneWay, 
                 Path=PositionString}"/></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock >Τηλέφωνο <Run Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>

                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        </ScrollViewer>
        </DockPanel>
        <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
            <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="30" Grid.Row="0">
                <Button.Content>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                        <TextBlock  FontSize="16">Προσθήκη Χρήστη</TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button.Content>
            </Button>
            <Label/>
        </DockPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Its all dependent on how much data you have in the ListBox.  I have tried this code populating listbox with 20 rows its not showing scrollbars at all

Comment: i want scrollbars.. All i want is listbox to be able to take all the height of its container .But i dont want it to be streched by default.if its height exceeds available space scrollbars should be shown.. Only star sizing works.But in a star sized row it is not easy to add a list and below it a button.If i put these two in a stackpanel they wont work.. Only solution seems to make buttons have top margin the listbox's height via binding but i dont know whether this will work.

Comment: The only way you can do that is if you have a container like dockpanel i have updated the code where DockPanel has a width and height. Wrap the listbox in the scrollviewer and then give the scrollbars visiblility auto so if the size changes and goes beyond the limit it will have the scroll bars untill then it will not have the scrollbars. ScrollViewer will do the trick for you.

Comment: From how I read the question he does NOT was a fixed size ListBox.

Comment: ya but somwhere we have to set the constraints like he dont want width to be stretched want height fixed how its possible if we do not set the constraints it will cover whole window..

Comment: @DOTNETBEE See my answer.  Use a calculated MaxHeight.  That way it grows but does not grow too much.  When you write "can do that" you imply it is and answer to the question so I commented.

Answer (score 0):

You might try auto for both and put a MaxHeight on the ListBox but you still take a chance of pushing the button off the screen.  Or put both in a ScrollViewer.  Or can you live with the button on top?

Comment: i can live even with button at bottom,but i cant understand why this is so hard to achieve..

Comment: if you are willing to write a converter for MaxHeight I am pretty sure you can do this.  Start with hard MaxHeight to see if that is the visual effect you want.